# Any Need for a Web Worker?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

I'm uploading a large (many GB) chunked binary file to the server using the HTML5 Files API etc.

In many places I've seen the iterative chunk uploading done in a separate Web Worker supposedly so that the work isn't happening on the main browser thread.

Is that approach really necessary though as `XMLHttpRequest#send` is asynchronous by default and would therefore be running in its own thread anyway? Or is that not what really happens and a Web Worker is necessary?

Basically is there anything "sub-optimal" with (pusdo code):

```
var blob = file.slice(start, finish);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url);
request.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
   if (request.readyState === 4) {
      increment start etc
      sendChunk();
   }
};
request.send(blob);
```

Comment: Can you please link some of those "many places"? From my intuition I'd follow your argumentation that the asynchronous tasks happen in the background anyway.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem-sync/

Answer (score 0):

non-blocking, asynchronous requests can mean that the appearance of concurrency is simulated. to ensure that concurrent threads executing in parallel you can use web workers.

Comment: But WebWorkers only do simulate concurrency as well?

Answer (score 0):

> supposedly so that the work isn't happening on the main browser thread.

No. To cite [the article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem-sync/) you linked:

> As expected, callbacks are gone with the synchronous FileReader. This
>   simplifies the amount of callback nesting when reading files. Instead,
>   the readAs* methods returns the read file.
>
> In some cases, the synchronous API is much cleaner for certain tasks.
>   Fewer callbacks are nice and certainly make things more readable.

Sure, starting and maintaining asynchronous is some work as well, and you might load that off to a WebWorker. However, the heavy lifting (reading files, doing network requests) is always done in the background anyway.

The article also mentions that WebWorkers create some overhead. Not only do you need to instantiate a Worker, you also need to copy all data that it is supposed to work with.

Comment: Yep, "callbacks are gone with the synchronous FileReader" - that's so your threaded web worker can block. But why go through all this hoopla at all?

Comment: Because the synchronous code for the web worker is easier to write, read and maintain. And often enough you don't want to do only IO, but also some computations with the results, for which the web worker does pay off.

Comment: Yep, I get that - basically I guess I'm trawling for one of the Chromium or Spidermonkey devs to give me an answer without having to go through the source code.

Comment: And as you said in your first comment on the original post: "From my intuition I'd follow your argument that the asynchronous tasks happen in the background anyway" - that's pretty much my thinking too.